# Is there a way to write a log of which options were selected, or which files were installed?

Tags: nsis

I have a bunch of options for which files need to be installed
It looks something like this:

```
SectionGroup /e "All" SEC0010
SectionGroup "A" SEC0020
    Section "A1"
        SectionIn 1 2
        File /r ".\Path\To\A1.txt"
    SectionEnd
    Section "A2"
        SectionIn 1 2
        File /r ".\Path\To\A2.txt"
    SectionEnd
    Section "A3"
        SectionIn 1 2
        File /r ".\Path\To\A3.txt"
    SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd
SectionGroup "B" SEC0020
    Section "B1"
        SectionIn 1 2
        File /r ".\Path\To\B1.txt"
    SectionEnd
    Section "B2"
        SectionIn 1 2
        File /r ".\Path\To\B2.txt"
    SectionEnd
    Section "B3"
        SectionIn 1 2
        File /r ".\Path\To\B3.txt"
    SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd
SectionGroup "C" SEC0030
    Section "C1"
        SectionIn 1 2
        File /r ".\Path\To\C1.txt"
    SectionEnd
    Section "C2"
        SectionIn 1 2
        File /r ".\Path\To\C2.txt"
    SectionEnd
    Section "AC3"
        SectionIn 1 2
        File /r ".\Path\To\C3.txt"
    SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd
SectionGroupEnd
```

I would like to write a log of which files were installed and/or which options were selected.

Ideally, it would look like the following:

```
2023-09-18 12:00:00|All
2023-09-18 12:01:00|C2
2023-09-18 12:02:00|A1, A2, B3, C1, C2
2023-09-18 12:03:00|All
```

Note: All the files are being installed in the same directory.

Is there a way to know which options were selected & write them to a file?

Alternatively, is there any way using something outside of NSIS, like a `.bat` file, that I could track which options were selected, or which files were installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily get the list of files but you can get the list of sections:

If you just want the list because you want to remember the configuration for the next time the installer runs, use Memento.nsh.

Or just loop from 0 until `SectionGetFlags` fails:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include Sections.nsh

Section
StrCpy $1 0
loop:
    ClearErrors
    SectionGetText $1 $2
    SectionGetFlags $1 $3
    IfErrors end
    IntOp $5 $3 & ${SF_SELECTED}
    IntOp $4 $3 & ${SF_SECGRP}
    IntOp $3 $3 & ${SF_SECGRPEND}
    ${If} $2 != ""
    ${AndIf} $5 <> 0 ; Must be checked
    ${AndIf} $4 = 0 ; Don't list groups
    ${AndIf} $3 = 0
        System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetLocalTime(p@r3)'
        System::Call '*$3(&i2.r4,&i2.r5,&i2,&i2.r6,&i2.r7,&i2.r8,&i2.r9)'
        IntFmt $5 "%.2u" $5
        IntFmt $6 "%.2u" $6
        IntFmt $7 "%.2u" $7
        IntFmt $8 "%.2u" $8
        IntFmt $9 "%.2u" $9
        DetailPrint "$4-$5-$6 $7:$8:$9|$2" ; TODO: Write to file
    ${EndIf}
    IntOp $1 $1 + 1
    Goto loop
end:
SectionEnd


Section "Root"
SectionEnd
SectionGroup "G1"
SectionGroup "G1.1"
Section "S1.1"
SectionEnd
Section "S1.2"
SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd
Section "S1"
SectionEnd
Section "S2"
SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd
```

Comment: It appears that this will still list items that were deselected

Comment: @Tyler Forgot about that :) Fixed now.